# pinax-admin: command not found

Tags: python, django, pinax

i am trying to install `pinax` in `django 1.4.0`. and I am using `git` to install pinax...

```
-e git+git://github.com/pinax/pinax.git#egg=pinax
```

now.. when i activate my `virtualenv`.

```
/djangoproj$ virtualenv mysite-env

New python executable in mysite-env/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...............done.

/djangoproj$ source mysite-env/bin/activate
/djangoproj$ pinax-admin setup_project mysite
pinax-admin: command not found
```

i got the error `pinax-admin: command not found`.

I am following this documentation http://pinax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gettingstarted.html#prerequisites

where did i go wrong? i did install `Pinax` in `git` so i don't need to install it in `pip` because it is already installed...

Does anyone have an idea on how can I deal with my case?

Comment: Could you repeat one more time, I didn't quite catch that.

Comment: This statement has a _few_ problems with it, and it's the source of your woes: "i did install Pinax in git so i don't need to install it in pip because it is already installed...".  

If there a reason you can't use 'pip install Pinax', make sure the virtualenv is activated before you run the install. The fact that the egg is on github isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to use a [pip requirements file](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html) with `pinax` and all the required modules to set up your environment. This way you can easily test your app in other hosts.

For the starting development environment:

- Create a `virtualenv`
- Install all you need with `pip`
- Create a requirements file: `pip freeze > requirements.txt` (this should be in your repo)
- Develop your app

For a new development environment:

- Create a `virtualenv`
- Clone your repo with your app and requirements.txt
- `pip -r requirements.txt`
- You're finished